# DynamoDB Update - ExpressionAttributeNames can only be specified when using expressions

Tags: amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I need another set of eyes on this. For the life of me I see no issues with this parameter set, used for Dynamo DocumentClient, **update** method - (here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#update-property ).

```
{
    TableName: "mygame-dev",
    Key: { pk: "09d017aa-cbf7-42ce-be6a-a94ecb58f9a7", sk: "GAME" },
    ExpressionAttributeNames: { "#GAMELASTUPDATED": "gameLastUpdated", "#GAMETITLE": "gameTitle" },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: { ":gamelastupdated": 1556376010704, ":gametitle": "test title 1" },
    UpdateExpression: "SET #GAMELASTUPDATED = :gamelastupdated, #GAMETITLE = :gametitle",
    ReturnValues: "ALL_NEW"
};
```

Error:

> ValidationException: ExpressionAttributeNames can only be specified
>   when using expressions

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6):

Disregard, this was a copy and paste issue... I was using "query" not "update"

**Was:**

> ```
> const updateGameResult = await ddbCall("query", params);
> ```

**Should have been:**

> ```
> const updateGameResult = await ddbCall("update", params);
> ```

Comment: Not really, according to the docs this expression can be used in query as well: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-dynamodb-2012-08-10.html#query